# Fix .value = undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate, that input is filled and it's working with two of my 3 inputs, but there is one input where I'm unable to figure at what is false.
Here's my HTML Code:

```
<form onsubmit="return !!(validateForms() & validatePosition() & validateName() & validateBranche())" class="form" name="form" action="assets/components/register.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
                                        <div id="name_error"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="position" placeholder="Position" id="position">
                                        <div id="position_error"></div>
                        <input type="text" name="branche" placeholder="Branche" id="branche">
                                        <div id="branche_error"></div>
                        <input type="number" name="random" placeholder="Number" id="random">
                        <input class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
                    </form>
```

and my JS Code:

```
function validateForms() {
  var position = document.getElementById("position");
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var branche = document.getElementById("branche");

  var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
  var position_error = document.getElementById('position_error');
  var branche_error = document.getElementById('branche_error');

}



function validateName() {
  alert(name.value);
  if (name.value == "") {
    name.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    name_error.style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "name is required";
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function validatePosition() {
  if (position.value == "") {
    position.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    position_error.style.color = "red";
    position_error.textContent = "position is required";
    position.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
function validateBranche() {
  if (branche.value == "") {
    branche.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    branche_error.style.color = "red";
    branche_error.textContent = "branche is required";
    branche.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

I actually have the same setup in all the functions, but when I do `alert(name.value)` I get as an output undefined.

Comment: `name` is not defined globally, but it's local to `validateForms`. Besides, are you sure you want to use the **bitwise AND** (&) here? `validateForms() & validatePosition() & validateName() & validateBranche()` sounds like you wanted the **logical AND** (&&) instead.

Comment: but it works for position and branche!

Comment: Remove the `var`s in validateForms. You want variables in global scope, not in function scope. The bitwise & actually makes sense if you want all validations to run.

Comment: @JonavonFriderici are you **sure** it works for position and branche?

Comment: I removed the vars, but it's still undefined!

Comment: yes, I'm sure! It definitely works.

Comment: @briosheje  It's because `name = window.name` here, as he's been using `id` attributes that pollute the global.  His `var position = ` actually doing nothing here.   And `window.positions` is not a standard variable, so `id` attribute will work.

Comment: If you only have to validate that the input elements have a value, just use the `required` attribute on the input. Then most of the code can go since the default browser styling will be used for required fields. ( which appropriately is a red border and focus() in most browsers. ) I also disagree that global variables should be used to fix the issue since that teaches people bad practices we'll have to un-teach 5 questions from now.

Comment: I need to verify more than just if there is value. But I started with this. I actually have done a lot of those form validations in my life, but I'm not able to fix this!

Comment: Since your code contains input type number, you can probably use most of the HTML5 validation tools for inputs like the pattern attribute, maxlength attribute etc. The issue you had, global variables, gets solved by the answers below. The whole bitwise `&` or not can be avoided by using `.addEventListener( 'submit', .... );` instead of using an inline `onsubmit=""` attribute, which I would always prefer over inline event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`validateForms()` is pointless - it serves simply to put references to HTML objects into global scope, where those could much more simply put into their specific methods in local scope.

Finally, you need some `return true` if you want it to ever submit the form.

```js
function validateName() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
  
  if (name.value == "") {
    name.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    name_error.style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "name is required";
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function validatePosition() {
  var position = document.getElementById("position");
  var position_error = document.getElementById('position_error');
  if (position.value == "") {
    position.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    position_error.style.color = "red";
    position_error.textContent = "position is required";
    position.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
function validateBranche() {
  var branche = document.getElementById("branche");
  var branche_error = document.getElementById('branche_error');
  if (branche.value == "") {
    branche.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    branche_error.style.color = "red";
    branche_error.textContent = "branche is required";
    branche.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return !!(validatePosition() & validateName() & validateBranche())" class="form" name="form" action="assets/components/register.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
                    <div id="name_error"></div>
    <input type="text" name="position" placeholder="Position" id="position">
                    <div id="position_error"></div>
    <input type="text" name="branche" placeholder="Branche" id="branche">
                    <div id="branche_error"></div>
    <input type="number" name="random" placeholder="Number" id="random">
    <input class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: It is completely sensible to use bitwise & if you want all validations to run.

Comment: Just a side design note (not relevant, but still): if you insert an invalid value and submit, then insert one valid value but other values are invalid, the warn on the valid value will not disappear, since styles are never reset. As a side note, the code can be singnificantly reduced by making a single validate function taking a DOM element as an argument and eventually a string to make the "textContent".

Comment: Thank you, Sir, it works. But I want it to run all those functions on submit and that doesn't work with && . And is there a simple code to reset the style?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
  var position;
  var name;
  var branche;

  var name_error;
  var position_error;
  var branche_error;
function validateForms() {
   position = document.getElementById("position");
   name = document.getElementById("name");
   branche = document.getElementById("branche");

   name_error = document.getElementById('name_error');
   position_error = document.getElementById('position_error');
   branche_error = document.getElementById('branche_error');

}



function validateName() {
  alert(name.value);
  if (name.value == "") {
    name.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    name_error.style.color = "red";
    name_error.textContent = "name is required";
    name.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function validatePosition() {
  if (position.value == "") {
    position.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    position_error.style.color = "red";
    position_error.textContent = "position is required";
    position.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
function validateBranche() {
  if (branche.value == "") {
    branche.style.borderBottom = "1px solid red";
    branche_error.style.color = "red";
    branche_error.textContent = "branche is required";
    branche.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

and that's because the scope of var is limited on the function then you should declace the variable outside the function(Globally) you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/var)

Comment: It might be better to use a different name for "name" variable.

Comment: Global variables where they're not needed. Bleugh.